# Make touchscreen working with Ubuntu 13.10 on Dell XPS13

Tags: drivers, 13.10, touchscreen

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my new Dell XPS 13 laptop but I cannot make the touchscreen working.

The OS sees the SYNAPTICS touchscreen:

```
ste@ste-XPS13-9333:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen    id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

It's enabled apparently:

```
Device 'SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen':
Device Enabled (134):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (136): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (264): 0
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (265):   1.000000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (266):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (267):    10.000000
Device Product ID (253):    1739, 2808
Device Node (254):  "/dev/input/event14"
Evdev Axis Inversion (268): 0, 0
Evdev Axis Calibration (269):   0, 2972, 0, 1680
Evdev Axes Swap (270):  0
Axis Labels (271):  "Abs MT Position X" (576), "Abs MT Position Y" (577), "None" (0), "None" (0)
Button Labels (272):    "Button Unknown" (256), "Button Unknown" (256), "Button Unknown" (256), "Button Wheel Up" (140), "Button Wheel Down" (141)
Evdev Middle Button Emulation (273):    0
Evdev Middle Button Timeout (274):  50
Evdev Third Button Emulation (275): 0
Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (276): 1000
Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (277):  3
Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (278):   20
Evdev Wheel Emulation (279):    0
Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (280):   0, 0, 4, 5
Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (281):    10
Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (282):    200
Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (283): 4
Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (284):  0
```

But when I start the calibration procedure:

```
xinput_calibrator 
Calibrating EVDEV driver for "SYNAPTICS Synaptics Large Touch Screen" id=15
```

The touchscreen just doesn't work. I checked and the driver is not blacklisted here /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf. I checked also here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen but no help.

Any idea?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just installed 13.10 on my XPS13 (9333) and enabled the touchscreen by installing the additional drivers available directly from Dell. The steps I followed were:

1. Visit the Dell Support site and entered the service tag for my XPS13
2. Selected Get Drivers > View All Drivers
3. Changed the selected OS to Ubuntu 12.04
4. Downloaded 'Ubuntu Driver Support Pack for Dell XPS 13 Haswell'
5. Extracted the contents of that file and installed 'config-usbhid-synaptics-touchscreen_1_all.deb'
6. Rebooted.

After that the touchscreen worked. I haven't installed any of the other drivers from the pack as everything else seems to be working ok.

Comment: It worked thx! Obvious, but I hadn't thought about it.

Comment: seems like you can get these here http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=4NTWR actually these are rather old. i would have thought most will be upstream