# no grub menu after ubuntu 15.10 install : dell xps 9350

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, dell

Was discussing my woes dual booting win10 and ubuntu on a new dell xps 13 9350 in [this q](https://askubuntu.com/questions/735123/trying-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-15-10-with-windows-10-new-dell-xps-9350), and thought this issue merited its own question.

**what I have done so far**

- did a clean install of win 10 with sata config set to ahci in bios
- disabled fast startup and hibernate in win 10
- did a shrink volume in win, creating about 140gb of unallocated space
- booted from the uefi usb drive with the ubuntu iso installed on it
- selected "try ubuntu"
- opened gparted, and was only able to see the 29gb usb drive where the install iso is located
- hit the install ubuntu icon
- selected "install alongside windows boot manager"
- install process went normally from there.

But now, when I boot into the system it just goes to win10. There is no grub menu, and no ubuntu option in bios.

The system contains a samsung ssd nvme (256gb). A couple of other questions have mentioned that as a possible issue.

here is a screenshot of my partitions in win10
[image: partition screenshot]

Anyone know how to resolve that? 
thanks!

Comment: from Windows 10 - post your partition picture. From what you described...you are only seeing 29GB -which is from USB and not actual unallocated space where you are trying to install ubuntu

Comment: screenshot added. The question stated that gparted is seeing the usb stick and not the sys hard drive, I think a downvote is unwarranted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that if you boot from ubuntu usb, install and use boot-repair it should do the trick.. helped me out with similar problems before.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: will try that. Think I need to get an ethernet dongle as I cannot connect to the internet booting from the usb

Comment: did not need internet connection. I made a live usb from boot repair and the default settings did the trick. Was able to boot into linux and windows successfully, VERY happy to have this resolved, thanks for all the help!!